# JavaScript: Get 90% of an integer, to the nearest integer?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Google Maps marker in JavaScript. Its height is created as a google.maps.Point, which must have an integer width and height.

Here's my problem. I want the width of the *shadow* of the marker to be 90% as tall as the height of the marker. I don't know the height in advance.

If I set:

```
var shadowDimensions = new google.maps.Point(height*0.9,height);
```

and `height*0.9` is not an integer, I get an error.

How can I define "`height*0.9` to the nearest integer" in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Math.round()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), which rounds to the nearest integer, with .5 cases rounded up:

```
var shadowDimensions = new google.maps.Point(Math.round(height*0.9),height);
```

Rounding to the next lesser integer (for negative numbers, away from zero) is accomplished using [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), and rounding to the next greater integer (for negative numbers, toward zero) is accomplished using [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil). See also [Wikipedia's article on rounding to an integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer).

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by nearest, but typically you'll want to use `Math.round()`. Alternatively, you could use `Math.floor()` (round down) or `Math.ceil()` (round up).

Answer (score 0):

```
var an_int = Math.round(a_float);
```

See also the spec for [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Answer (score 0):

use [Math.round()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp) method

Answer (score 0):

I know that Javascript has a Round function, I don't recall the syntax off the top of my head.

Maybe something like :

```
var shadowDimensions = new google.maps.Point(Math.Round(height*0.9),height);
```

or perhaps a ceiling / floor function?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `parseInt(height*0.9)`

Comment: This would be the same as `Math.floor`, which might be unexpected.